# How to hide Assistant/Activities tab and Attach button in Notes section on Social Pane in Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-365-v9

Has anyone had an experience modifying the Social Pane in Dynamics 365?

1. Hiding the Assistant and Activities Tab
2. Hiding the Attach button in the Notes Tab

Googling shows unsupported way by accessing and hiding by DOM manipulation. Has tried Security roles, Ribbon Workbench but still tabs and Attach button are showing. The Notes form also cannot be customized.

We tried also the Intelligence Configuration by following this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/sales-enterprise/configure-enable-embedded-intelligence

But nothing changed.

Can you share your experience on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The social pane is a disappointing feature. The only two things you can change is the order of the activities displayed and the default tab.

If you want to prevent your user from attaching files to notes, you can make a plugin on the creation of the note and throw an exception.

To hide the other tabs, the only way I can think of is unsupported. Using javascript. I don't like it but when my clients are asking for it, I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we don't have lot of control over there to customize Social Pane the way we want. Maximum we can configure that what should be the default tab (Supported Customization).

Dynamics 365 got Timeline control (Social Pane 2.0) which has more doors open like: Timeline is available in Mobile, Dashboards, unified experience, filtering options, etc. But only catch: it is available only in Unified Interface (UCI App aka model-driven PowerApp & Hub apps) and not on Standard Web client.

[image]

[Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmpowerobjects/archive/2018/06/01/timeline-the-new-and-improved-social-pane-in-d365-unified-interfaces)

Embedded Intelligence will enhance Relationship Assistant experience.

[image]