# What is Timeline in MS Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

Which entity does represent it? How to get data from it using WEB API?
I do not find any information about how to fetch data from 'Timeline' window on account and contact entities. Is it possible to query all necessary info using /api/data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeline is not an entity and not expose via web api endpoint. It's a custom PCF control (maybe) and all about a placeholder for showing all activities, Notes, Posts for that particular record in chronological order. Btw, Timeline can be added to Dashboard also. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51367839/7920473)

You can pull all the activities, Notes (annotation), Post feed & display in the same fashion if you build a portal separately.